# Python UnboundLocalError: Problems with a function for choosing words from a dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary, if-statement, random

I've written a function for choosing a single key (=word) from a dictionary. If the key has already been used, another key should be chosen. This is my function:

```
nom_acc = {"qeso":"qes", "os":"os", "sondra":"sondre", "mawizzi":"mawizze", "khewo":"khewe", "alegra":"alegre", "kendra":"kendre", "zhalia":"zhalie", "achrakh":"achrakh", "ador":"ador", "hoggi":"hogge", "soqwi":"soqwe"}
usedWords = []

def wordChoice():
    global usedWords
    print(usedWords) ### DELETE LATER

    word = random.choice(list(nom_acc))     ### randomly pick a key from a dictionary (which is the nominative form)
    print(word) ### DELETE LATER 
    if word in usedWords: 
        print("gotta pick another word") ### DELETE LATER
        wordChoice() 
    else: 
        usedWords.append(word)          
        accusative = nom_acc[word]

    return word, accusative
```

The function is embedded into a main program. When I run the code like this, it gives me an error message as soon as a word is chosen that has already been used: 
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'accusative' referenced before assignment`

If I add a dummy value for the word and accusative variable it seems to work:

```
    if word in usedWords: 
        print("gotta pick another word") ### DELETE LATER
        word="DUMMY"
        accusative="DUMMY"
```

But what I want is that another word is chosen from the dictionary if the word has already been used. How do I implement this?

Comment: put your return statement into else block

Comment: Just tried it, but the program still gives me an error message after picking a word that has already been used: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

This is the part of the code where the wordChoice() function is called up:

```
def writeAcc():
    '''Minigame: User has to enter the correct accusative form, after three correct answers he passed'''

    global isPlaying, usedWords
    isPlaying = True

# asking the user to enter the right accusative form of the word        
    print("Please enter the accusative form of the following words\n")

# player passed when he reached 3 correct answers
    right = 0
    while right < 4:
        word, accusative = wordChoice()

        print("Nominative ", word)

        print("Need help? Enter 'y' to see the menu again or press the enter-key to continue.")
        choice = input("\t\t\tChoice: ")
        if choice == 'y':
            continueGame = displayMenu()
            if not continueGame:
                return
            print("Nominative ", word)

        answer=input("Accusative ")
        if answer==accusative:
            right+=1

        print("Guessed right:", right)

        if right < 4 and (len(usedWords) == len(list(nom_acc))):
            print("Sorry you don't seem to have what it takes to learn the accusative.")
            break

    if right == 4:
        print("Congratulations! You passed the first step, you will now enter the next challenge.")
```

Comment: please add an update to your question, don't post this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because there is a problem in your recursiveness. Below I will try to explain the problem in your recursion. Suppose this is your input in the terminal with your current code:

```
wordChoice()
```

Python interpreter will then evaluate the expression by running the code within `def wordChoice()` block. Everything will run smoothly until your `if` block. Your current `if block is like this`:

```
if word in usedWords: 
    print("gotta pick another word") ### DELETE LATER
    wordChoice() # Python must evaluate this before continuing
```

When your `word` is used, Python will get to that new `wordChoice()` and it will evaluate that expression **before continuing**. Suppose that when running this second `wordChoice()` the randomised `word` is not used, and the code reaches your `else` block.

```
else: 
    usedWords.append(word)          
    accusative = nom_acc[word]
```

No problem here either, everything smooth, it will `return word, accusative` just like you wanted. This `return` statement is telling Python how it should evaluate the **last called** `wordChoice()`. Which means that it will go back from where it stopped the last time `wordChoice()` was called, which is that `if` statement. So it will proceed like this:

```
if word in usedWords: 
    print("gotta pick another word") ### DELETE LATER
    some_word, some_accusative_value # the interpreter will continue the code from this point
else: 
    usedWords.append(word)          
    accusative = nom_acc[word]

return word, accusative
```

Which means that the `if` block is executed and it will proceed to the `return word, accusative` again, but in the scope of this current `wordChoice()` they are not set because this `wordChoice()` did not get to the `else` statement. To correct your recursiveness, you must `return wordChoice()` until the code gets to executes the `else` statement. Below is the correct solution for what you want:

```
nom_acc = {"qeso":"qes", "os":"os", "sondra":"sondre", "mawizzi":"mawizze", "khewo":"khewe", "alegra":"alegre", "kendra":"kendre", "zhalia":"zhalie", "achrakh":"achrakh", "ador":"ador", "hoggi":"hogge", "soqwi":"soqwe"}

usedWords = []

def wordChoice():
    global usedWords
    print(usedWords) ### DELETE LATER

    word = random.choice(list(nom_acc))     ### randomly pick a key from a dictionary (which is the nominative form)
    print(word) ### DELETE LATER 
    if word in usedWords: 
        print("gotta pick another word") ### DELETE LATER
        return wordChoice() # return correct recursive result 
    else: 
        usedWords.append(word)          
        accusative = nom_acc[word]
        return word, accusative # This return statement should be inside the else statement for clearness
```